# Alexa not stopping audio playing in custom skill

Tags: java, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am facing an issue stopping audio in Alexa , 
I have a skill that playing audio in skill but when i say stop , alexa is not stopping audio although i am sending StopDirecotry with response .
Please help me .
Any help would be appreciable .

Comment: Is there any problem that amazon alexa facing right now regarding to the AudioInterface ?

Answer (score 0):

If audio is playing, the "AMAZON.PauseIntent" is invoked instead of the stop intent. This took me couple hours to realize, maybe it's your problem too...

Comment: For that instance , i already put the same code for the both of the Intents .
And that code was working perfectly , but now after amazon applied their new dashboard ,it suddenly stopped working .
I shoot an email to them about this . But did not get any replay . 
Now i don't know whether it is my fault or theirs .
So do you have any suggestions for that ?

Comment: @Viergelenker Can we keep both `AMAZON.PauseIntent` and `AMAZON.StopIntent`?

Comment: Sure, you can use the PauseIntent if a user says "Alexa stop" during playback and the StopIntent if the song actually finished playing. 
For example i save the current playback time if Pause is invoked and do nothing on StopIntent.